# How to completely reset iMessage on MacOS X Catalina 10.15.4?

Tags: messages, catalina, bug, restart

I have an iMac with two user accounts.  After updating to MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 one of the two users cannot use iMessage anymore.  iMessage just wont start.  Starting it results in

- iMessage immediately becoming "unresponsive" without ever displaying any window.
- It can be "quit immediately"
- The user cannot log out until iMessage is "quit immediately"
- Works just fine for the other user on this iMac
- Works just fine on all other devices (iOS and other MacOS devices of the affected user)
- iMessage on iCloud was disabled for this user when the 10.15.4 update was done
- When iMessage is not started (and crashed) the badge on the icon does correctly update with the number of unread message!

My idea was to completely reset iMessage to factory state, but I don't know how to do it.  Things I have tried

- Logging out of iCloud and back in
- Restoring this user from a time machine backup
- Deleting preferences and IdentityServices as in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171707/how-can-i-completely-reset-imessage-in-yosemite) and [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8278462) (there is no McAffee used here).

The behaviour is all the same.  The only thing I've not gone through is to let the user start from scratch with a new user account.  This would be quite painful.

Comment: I call it IMessage, but of course it is called "Messages" now...